# Optimizing the area of a rectangle with one side against a wall using the am-gm inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

Given 300 meters of fence, how can I find the dimensions of a rectangle that is built against a wall the encloses the maximum area. I found this question in a calculus book and saw a simple solution in which the derivative function of the area was set to zero. Is it possible to solve this problem using the am-gm inequality? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to find $x>0,y>0$ that maximize $xy$ subject to $2x+y \le 300$. This is straightforward by AM-GM inequality $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a+b}{2}$ with $a=2x, b=y$.